# How can I check value to be inserted in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

Please I'm a newbie in php and mysql I want you to help me on how to check if value to be inserted into a database is greater than or lesser than, if greater than it should insert pass, thanks.

this the code

```
$query="select * from ats_question";
$rs=mysql_query("select * from ats_question where test_id=$tid",$cn) or  die(mysql_error());
if(!isset($_SESSION[qn]))
{
$_SESSION[qn]=0;
mysql_query("delete from ats_useranswer where sess_id='" . session_id() ."'") or die(mysql_error());
$_SESSION[trueans]=0;

}
else
{   
        if($submit1=='Next Question' && isset($ans))
    {
            mysql_data_seek($rs,$_SESSION[qn]);
            $row= mysql_fetch_row($rs); 
mysql_query("insert into ats_useranswer(sess_id, test_id, que_des, ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,
                true_ans,your_ans)values('".session_id()."', $tid,'$row[2]','$row[3]','$row[4]','$row[5]', '$row[6]','$row[7]','$ans')") or die(mysql_error());
            if($ans==$row[7])
            {
                        $_SESSION[trueans]=$_SESSION[trueans]+1;
            }
            $_SESSION[qn]=$_SESSION[qn]+1;
    }
    else if($submit=='Get Result' && isset($ans))
    {
            mysql_data_seek($rs,$_SESSION[qn]);
            $row= mysql_fetch_row($rs); 
mysql_query("insert into ats_useranswer(sess_id, test_id, que_des, ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,true_ans,
    your_ans) values 
('".session_id()."', $tid,'$row[2]','$row[3]','$row[4]','$row[5]', '$row[6]','$row[7]','$ans')") or die(mysql_error());
            if($ans==$row[7])
            {
                        $_SESSION[trueans]=$_SESSION[trueans]+1;
            }
            echo "<h1 class=head1> Result</h1>";
            $_SESSION[qn]=$_SESSION[qn]+1;
            echo "<Table align=center><tr class=tot><td>Total Question<td> $_SESSION[qn]";
            echo "<tr class=tans><td>True Answer<td>".$_SESSION[trueans];
            $w=$_SESSION[qn]-$_SESSION[trueans];
            echo "<tr class=fans><td>Wrong Answer<td> ". $w;
            echo "</table>";
            mysql_query("insert into ats_result(login,test_id,grade,score) values
                ('$login',$tid,grade,$_SESSION[trueans])")
             or die(mysql_error());
            echo "<h1 align=center><a href=ats_review.php> Review Question</a> </h1>";
            unset($_SESSION[qn]);
            unset($_SESSION[sid]);
            unset($_SESSION[tid]);
            unset($_SESSION[trueans]);
            exit;
    }
 }
$rs=mysql_query("select * from ats_question where test_id=$tid",$cn) or      die(mysql_error());
if($_SESSION[qn]>mysql_num_rows($rs)-1)
{
unset($_SESSION[qn]);
echo "<h1 class=head1>Some Error  Occured</h1>";
session_destroy();
echo "Please <a href=index.php> Start Again</a>";

exit;
}
mysql_data_seek($rs,$_SESSION[qn]);
$row= mysql_fetch_row($rs);
echo "<div align=\"center\" class=\"style2\"><strong> Ats Examination     </strong></div>";
echo "<div id=\"\"></div>";

    echo"<p id=\"note\"></p>";
echo "<form name=myfm id=myfm1 method=post action=ats_exam.php>";
echo "<table width=100%> <tr> <td width=30>&nbsp;<td> <table border=0>";
$n=$_SESSION[qn]+1;
echo "<tR><td><span class=style2>Que ".  $n .": $row[2]</style>";
echo "<tr><td class=style6><input type=radio name=ans value=1>$row[3]";
echo "<tr><td class=style6> <input type=radio name=ans value=2>$row[4]";
echo "<tr><td class=style6><input type=radio name=ans value=3>$row[5]";
echo "<tr><td class=style6><input type=radio name=ans value=4>$row[6]";

if($_SESSION[qn]<mysql_num_rows($rs)-1)
echo "<tr><td><input type=submit name=submit1 value='Next Question'>   </form>";

echo "<tr><td><input type=submit name=submit value='Get Result'></form>";
echo "</table></table>";
?>
```

i want to check if the trueans is greater than 15 it should insert pass if not fail in the grade value

```
 mysql_query("insert into ats_result(login,test_id,grade,score) values
            ('$login',$tid,grade,$_SESSION[trueans])")
```

Comment: You need to show us your code...??

Comment: `if(condition) <= || >= {...} else{...}`

Comment: @James Lordie; this one would fall almost any category. Either too broad, unclear, primarily opinion-based, duplicate of etc; anyone of those lol

Comment: **Value = what?!** Time? Number? Longitude? Latitude? Weight? Cost? Height? Compared to? IQ? - *other?* - *None of the above?*

Comment: @James I chose as "unclear", as per ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^

Comment: I'm finding it real hard to paste the code.. The insert query is insert I'd Subject Score Grade  into ats_exam value I'd Subject Score Grade .... I want the grade to check the score if the score is greater than 15 it should insert pass in grade field and if it is not it should insert fail. Sorry for my bad grammar or code.

Comment: Do up a pastebin file then, copy the URL for it then paste it in your question.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Lol @ IQ - I see what you did there.

Comment: I'm using a local host

Comment: Mate, if you're struggling to paste code into your question then you probably shouldn't be using anything at all.

Comment: @The Blue Dog is showing some error when I tried to saved it.. Be calm with be bro, I'm new here.

Comment: ive finally pasted my code please help me out

Comment: @tramp i have posted my code

Answer (score 1):

Thanks I have finally get solution to my question this what my code now look like `mysql_query("insert into ats_result(login,test_id,score,grade)values('$login','$tid',$_SESSION[trueans],IF($_SESSION[trueans]>=10,'Pass','Fail')");`   thanks all for the response and challenges throw to me.